# Growing multiple stems on Dracaena

Tags: growth, dracaena

First I must say, I am not quite sure the plant is really a Dracaena…

Well, I see lot of similar plants growing a "multiple" head with several stems but mine is only growing straight up.

I have been researching a little bit about growing but my native tongue isn't -English and the translator doesn't help me that much when searching for the terms.

So far, I see I have to cut the top of the plant and seal it so it has to start growing from the laterals. Is this the only way?

Can I just cut some leaves and insert them to the main stem and they will grow from there?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like *Dracaena marginata* alright. To get more stems, the way to go is topping it (cut off the top of the plant). New shoots will grow from the stem, however there is a chance that only one new shoot will grow. I am not sure how to stimulate more shoots to develop, I think it might be a matter of timing (topping it in the right season). Best chances are to top it in Springtime, when everything starts to grow.

Comment: To add to this, you can try keeping the top you cut off (as a cutting). With a bit of luck, if you just put it in a pot with potting soil, it will grow roots and survive.

Comment: You can easily root these in water - pop what you cut off in a narrow necked bottle full of water and stand it on a windowsill. Should take about 4-6 weeks for roots to from, then pot it up in potting soil.